# Can not create a new Model version

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, database-migration

I have an old project (made for iOS4).
I am upgrading it now and try to add a model version to my Core Data model.

When I am trying to add the version from Xcode menu, it simply create a new version of the model and does not create the .modeld package.

I tried to change it manually but it douses many problems and the migration fails.

1. Why it won't let me create the .modeld file ?
2. Any idea how can I overcome this problem ?

Here is the image from Xcode navigator -

[image]

While it should be -

[image]

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

1. Xcode will always create a `.xcdatamodel` file for new model
   versions. `.xcdatamodeld` is a file package that groups versions
   of the model.
2. There's a workaround that you can do:

   - Create a new `Data Model` (`File` > `New` > `File...` > `Core Data` > `Data Model`) and give the model the same name as your current version (e.g. `jerusalemBiblicalZoo`).
   - Reveal the created `jerusalemBiblicalZoo.xcdatamodeld` on Finder
   - Right click on the file and select `Show Package Contents` so you will see a `.xcdatamodel` file there.
   - Override it with your old `.xcdatamodel` file. Then you will have the new data model structure using your old single model version.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create new version for coreData, don't recreate xcdatamodel.Click jerusalemBiblicalZoo.xcdatamodel and go to Editor->Add Model Version select base model and go on.

Comment: Read my question again. This is what I am doing. Thanks anyway